# All black rendering

Tags: rendering, export, image, uv-image-editor, photorealism

Im new using the software and a lot of are things are being very difficult for me  to understand .. I've already watched some tutorials of how to fix this problem but nothing seems to work[image: image 001]

the material of the objects are divided in windows and building.. and the shading tab for both with the "emit" option to check doesn't appear to me .. How is it possible to render the image exactly like it is on cycles render ? always when i change to blender render the objects get black, and to get worse, when i render .. all it appears is a full black screen [image]
[image]

every time i try to fix the situation it only gets worse by using the wrong commands and now the project is a mess
i appreciate any one who can help me on this, i just want to export a simple picture of these buildings to make a concept art image on photoshop nothing beyond that

[image]

[image]

Comment: switch back to the cycles renderer

Comment: already switched, but the same grey screen appears when i press F12 to render

Comment: I think it would help a lot if you used the latest version of Blender, and not years old outdated versions. Unless of course you specifically need it for something.

Comment: I thought about that but my windows is the windows 7.. I'll see if there is a way to use 2.93 with windows 7

Comment: You can use version 2.83 with Windows 7. Click [this](https://www.blender.org/download/releases/2-83/) link to go to the download page.

Answer (score 0):

**1) Create a camera, and make it face the object?**

1. Tip: Shift A > Camera
2. Tip: Go to Preferences > Keymap > 3D View | View Camera - assign hotkey, I use C.
3. Tip: Go to Preferences > Keymap > 3D view | View Navigation(walk/fly) and assign a hotkey, I use alt, `. This will let you control the camera like it was a first person game **(must be in view camera)**

**2) Create some lights and make them face the object you want to render?**

1. Tip: There is a handy addon called Tri-lighting : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s6Asw9_2a_c&t=283s